# ToList() taking too long to execute

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitefinity

I am beginner in asp.net and I am working with a asp.net website in sitefinity. There is a custom widget on a page because of which the page load time drops to 2 mins.

After lot of research I found that ToList() could be the reason for this slowness. Below is the C# code of the widget containing the ToList().

```
namespace SitefinityWebApp.CustomControls
{
    public partial class DashboardRole : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<bl.CustomItem> classificationList = bl.module.GetClassifications(bl.config.classification_assets_name, "", bl.config.data_asset_content_type);
            classificationList = classificationList.OrderByDescending(o => o.ItemsCount).ToList();
            rptMainClassifications.DataSource = classificationList;
            rptMainClassifications.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anyone have faced such issue earlier. Any help would mean a lot.

Edit : This is how GetClassifications() looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsnrW.jpg

Comment: The expensive operation is `OrderByDescending()`, not `ToList()` and even that shouldn't take too long unless you load a lot more data than can be displayed on a web page. You don't have to call `ToList()` before setting the `DataSource`. You'll see there's no difference in performance though

Comment: Besides, are you sure the delay isn't caused by the *first* line? What does `GetClassifications` do and how many items are there in `classificationList`? If `GetClassifications` queries a database, why not have the *database* order the results before returning them?

Comment: `ItemsCount` could be hiding complexity

Comment: Indeed, if `ItemsCount` executes a `SELECT COUNT(*)` for each item you can end with 101 queries for 100 result items. Use SQL Server Profiler or Extended Events to see what queries get executed.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question but i never found SQL queries for this widget in any cs file.. Do you know where the queries are written?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you were right GetClassifications look to create the slowness.. I have posted an image in my question of the code of GetClassification. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**I'm pretty sure that this is not because of ToList() method.**
*ToList() just convert your IEnumerable() or other list to simple c# List().*
There is another problem. And your question have not enough content to understand the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help. What else you think can be the reason? Should i post a screenshot of the corresponding ascx file ?